# UV unwrap shows black Alpha in the Object

Tags: uv-image-editor

The image alpha seems to be fine. I retouched it again with Gimp. I have the 2 versions in the file ( see file attached ).

I tried several suggestions I found on the net, but nothing seemed to work.

I tried it in a new file.

can someone take a look, please.

[image]

Comment: Please fully describe your problem textually and provide some images of the problem and what you have tried and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cycles, transparency have to be explicitly handled.

Here is the kind of node setting you need (and the transparency will be visible in rendered mode only, see the green square below):

[image]

- Use a "mix shader" to balance between diffuse node and transparency
- The mix shader is driven by 'alpha' value of the image: when transparent, alpha = 0 so the mix shader uses transparency, when opaque, alpha=1 and the mix shader uses the diffuse.

Comment: Super Lemon, thanks a lot it worked. And very easy to understand and follow, super well explained.